# Label Property Inspector won't show

Tags: livecode

I am following the video tutorial for Simple Messages in App Building Courses.  When I add the Label object to the header area, and click "Inspector" nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: A short code might help to better understand your problem. :)

Comment: Not sure what the issue was but I exited LiveCode and restarted it and the property inspector now works on the label.

Comment: I'm not even advanved user but perhaps things like cache or settings that required restart stayed before restarting server.